# unable to close access form after update

Tags: ms-access

I made a minor change to an access form on tuesday and closed it fine, but since then I need to make another change and it will not allow me to close the form after I save the changes. No error message, it just keeps asking me would I like to save changes. I looked on google and one site said unclick the AutoCorrect but this did not work at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would start with a compact and repair.  Is this happening with any other forms?

Comment: I tried compact and repair... no change, and yes other forms are doing the same, I thought it was linked tables... so I made a copy and deleted the linked tables but the form is still having the same issue

Comment: Do you ever set `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` because leaving that as false and not setting back to true (how it should be) can cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost sounds as though your database is having issues writing to itself, either a permission issue or a simple saving issue.  Try to import all of your forms into a new blank database.

Comment: No problem, I tend to follow the rule that if I run into an issue that makes absolutely no sense, compact & repair, if that doesn't work import into another database.